# How to develop the static and kinetic friction formula?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

How do you end up with the formula for [Amontons' first law of friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Amontons#Amontons.27_Laws_of_Friction)? ($F_s = \mu_s \times N$) or ($F_k = \mu_k \times N$). I know how to use the formula. Now I need to know how to get to it.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. In order for someone to be able to answer this question, that person would first need to know what the symbols in your equation mean.

Answer (score 1):

The relation is empirically observed across a wide range of materials and conditions.  But it is not exact.  Attempting to derive a similar equation just from lower-level physics such as solid surface molecular interactions would be horribly complex.